# How to join and transpose row to columns in redshift

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift, pivot-table

I have following `table1` and its unique key is `type`

```
type age
A     20
B     21
C     22
```

And I have following result table. I'd like to join them as

```
type score
A     10
A     20
A     30
B     40 
B     50
```

following transposed form.

```
type  age  score score score
A     20    10    20    30
B     21    40    50    na
C     22    na    na    na
```

Are there any way to achieve this?

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 usint(type)
```

Didn't transpose rows.
If someone has opinion please let me know
thanks

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different database systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know in advance the number of `score` values per type, then you need a full dynamic solution :

First we create a composite type `new_type` according to the maximum number of `score` values per type in `table2`. This composite type is then used for naming the columns in the final query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE new_type() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  column_txt text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(' score' || id || ' integer', ',')
   INTO column_txt
    FROM
       (  SELECT count(*) AS count
           FROM table2
          GROUP BY type
          ORDER BY 1 DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS a
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, a.count :: integer) AS id ;
     
  EXECUTE 'DROP TYPE IF EXISTS new_type' ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE new_type AS (' || column_txt || ')' ;
END ;
$$ ;

CALL new_type() ;
```

Then this query will provide the expected result :

```
SELECT c.type, c.age
     , (jsonb_populate_record( NULL :: new_type
                             , jsonb_object_agg('score' || c.id, c.score ORDER BY c.score)
                             )).*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.type, a.age, b.score, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.type, a.age ORDER BY b.score) AS id
         FROM table1 AS a
         LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
           ON a.type = b.type
     ) AS c
 GROUP BY c.type, c.age
 ORDER BY c.type, c.age
```

The test result is in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=805394fe4ff05b81f3298fbd19a09bae).