# PIVOT/crosstab: I wan to return dynamic columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, postgres-crosstab

I just want to return a dynamic columns out of cross tab, column names based out of query result. Header is lookup from different table like Types.

any help appreciated. so far i could able to get hard coded columns.

for example

Result 1:

| header | B header | C header | D header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 111 | 12 | 1 |
| Second | 33 | 34 | 0 |

Result 2:

| header | X header | Y header | D header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 11 | 123 | 11 |
| Second | 313 | 343 | 12 |

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
$$
    SELECT property, name, count(prm_id)
    FROM vw_ex_insp_sum
    WHERE prm_id = 1
    AND date_t BETWEEN '2021/01/01' AND '2021/1/31'
    GROUP BY property, name
    HAVING count(prm_id) >0
$$,
$$
    SELECT name FROM lookup WHERE l_type=12
    ORDER BY vit 
$$
) AS final_result (
    Name2 varchar,
    "Annual (365)" bigint, "Follow-Up (30)" bigint, "3" bigint, "4" bigint, "5" bigint ,
    name_0 bigint, name_1 bigint, "8" bigint, "Indicator (Post-Event)" bigint, "10" bigint ,
    "11" bigint, "12" bigint, "13" bigint, "14" bigint, "15" bigint ,
    "16" bigint
);
```

Comment: Not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and types of the columns of a query must be known before the query starts running.

Comment: Thanks, let me try the other option that Edouard posted

Answer (score 2):

Here below are two examples for implementing a full dynamic pivot-table solution instead of using `crosstab` :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466824/8060017

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70695023/8060017

Comment: Thanks, im trying to get in. Have you used CROSSTABVIEW ? i need a help to get this called from ruby. is this still possible?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Crosstabview

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked many times, & there are decent *(even dynamic)* solutions. While CROSSTAB() is available in recent versions of Postgres, not everyone has sufficient user privileges to install the prerequisite extension.

One such solution involves a *[**temp type** (temp table) created by **an anonymous function** & **JSON expansion** of the resultant type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360/how-to-pivot-or-crosstab-in-postgresql-without-writing-a-function/73804975#73804975)*

Stack Overflow: [How to pivot or crosstab in postgresql without writing a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299360/how-to-pivot-or-crosstab-in-postgresql-without-writing-a-function/73804975#73804975)

See also: [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/m3mms0-0) (UK): https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL